# Sitecore MultiList showing Standard Values

Tags: content-editor

Using Sitecore 9.0.1, in a MultiList with Search field with a Source set as

> StartSearchLocation=/sitecore/content/Parks/Home/Places&Filter=_template:{BCE4E2CA-ACA5-446E-B363-9635B92C7278}|_template:{C025B0A6-E273-4126-9E08-CD6428B3154C}|_template:{F230C330-4B09-46B7-A738-C02343545CD4}`

We are seeing the standard values template item appear in the Content Editor (the standard values aren't in that list of guids for templates above):

[image]

i.e. {BCE4E2CA-ACA5-446E-B363-9635B92C7278} is the 'Experience' template but the standard values are appearing in the Multilist despite having a different ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your StartSearchLocation isn't taken into account and searches the whole Sitecore tree for items with those 3 templates. Which will match the __Standard Values and thus show up in the result list.

You can test this by creating an item from 1 of those 3 templates into a different location and verify that it also shows up.

Conclusion: Your StartSearchLocation is not defined properly.

To fix it:

1. Either use the ID of the 'Places' item: StartSearchLocation={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}
2. Or use query: StartSearchLocation=query:/sitecore/content/Parks/Home/Places

So this should definitely work:

```
StartSearchLocation=query:/sitecore/content/Parks/Home/Places&Filter=_template:{BCE4E2CA-ACA5-446E-B363-9635B92C7278}|_template:{C025B0A6-E273-4126-9E08-CD6428B3154C}|_template:{F230C330-4B09-46B7-A738-C02343545CD4}
```

Good overview of possibilities: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/using-the-new-sitecore-7-field-types